# How can I act on the last created node in my jelastic installation manifest?

Tags: jelastic

I have the following jps manifest:

```yaml
jpsVersion: 1.3
jpsType: update
application:
  id: test
  name: Test
  version: 0.0

  onInstall:
  - addNodes:
    - nodeType: docker
      count: 1
      fixedCloudlets: 1
      cloudlets: 16
      dockerName: gitlab/gitlab-runner

  onAfterAddNode:
  - installDocker

  actions:
    installDocker:
    - cmd:
      - myDockerInstallScript.sh
```

My problem is that the `onAfterAddNode` actions are not called, even though the node was added successfully. What am I doing wrong? How can I guarantee the commands will be run on the added node only?

### EDIT

My use case is the following: I have created an environment a while ago, which I would like to add new nodes to. Therefore, I need to update that environment with the addition of new nodes and with some installation steps on those new nodes.

Comment: Laurent, can you describe what you want to achieve? Why do you use type: update and addNodes instead of using type:install with pre-defined nodes, for example like here https://github.com/jelastic-jps/jitsi/blob/master/manifest.yaml#L18?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to perform an action only in a newly created node, then you can do it like this:

```
jpsVersion: 1.3
jpsType: update
application:
  id: test
  name: Test
  version: 0.0
  onInstall:
  - addNodes:
      nodeType: docker
      count: 1
      nodeGroup: runner
      fixedCloudlets: 1
      cloudlets: 16
      dockerName: gitlab/gitlab-runner
  - installDocker: ${nodes.runner.last.id}
  actions:
    installDocker:
    - cmd [${this}]:
      - myDockerInstallScript.sh
```

Also, thanks for the comment about the documentation, we have updated it: https://docs.cloudscripting.com/creating-manifest/actions/#addnodes

Answer (score 0):

The execution of other events in the environment occurs only after the successful completion of the onInstall event. The onAfterAddNode event will run the next time a node is added. [Here](https://docs.cloudscripting.com/creating-manifest/events/#events-execution-sequence) you can see the sequence of events. If you just need to call the action during installation, then you need to do this in onInstall:

Example:

```
jpsVersion: 1.3
jpsType: update
application:
  id: test
  name: Test
  version: 0.0
  onInstall:
  - addNodes:
    - nodeType: docker
      count: 1
      fixedCloudlets: 1
      cloudlets: 16
      dockerName: gitlab/gitlab-runner
  - installDocker
  actions:
    installDocker:
    - cmd:
      - myDockerInstallScript.sh
```

If it is necessary that a certain action is also performed each time a node is added to the topology of the environment, then you can do this such way:

```
jpsVersion: 1.3
jpsType: update
application:
  id: test
  name: Test
  version: 0.0
  onInstall:
  - addNodes:
    - nodeType: docker
      count: 1
      nodeGroup: runner
      fixedCloudlets: 1
      cloudlets: 16
      dockerName: gitlab/gitlab-runner
  - installDocker
 onAfterAddNode [runner]:
  - installDocker
  actions:
    installDocker:
    - cmd [runner]:
      - myDockerInstallScript.sh
```

If you want a specific action to be performed after scaling the entire layer, then you can do it this way:

```
jpsVersion: 1.3
jpsType: update
application:
  id: test
  name: Test
  version: 0.0
  onInstall:
  - addNodes:
    - nodeType: docker
      count: 1
      nodeGroup: runner
      fixedCloudlets: 1
      cloudlets: 16
      dockerName: gitlab/gitlab-runner
  - installDocker
 onAfterScaleOut [runner]:
  forEach(event.response.nodes):
    installDocker: ${@i.id} 
  actions:
    installDocker:
    - cmd [${this}]:
      - myDockerInstallScript.sh
```

Comment: If I apply your first proposition, I get the warning `WARNING: cmd.response: {"result":11022,"source":"marketplace","error":"can't find node by the given parameters ","type":"warning"}`, probably because I run the `cmd` without specifying a node group. How do I ensure that the commands in my `cmd` are only run on the node I've just added?

Comment: Setting the `nodegroup` to `runner` in the `addNodes` action doesn't work either. I get the very same warning: `WARNING: cmd [runner].response: {"result":11022,"source":"marketplace","error":"can't find node by the given parameters [nodeGroup = runner]","type":"warning"}`. I don't think that is surprising, as it is not documented [here](https://docs.cloudscripting.com/creating-manifest/actions/#addnodes). So, currently, I still have no solution to my problem.

Comment: Then, I've tried to use `cmd [docker]` in my actions, but then the actions are applied to the already installed nodes of nodeType `docker`, not only the node I've installed last.

Comment: In fact, the only solution I currently have is to first manually create the new docker node in my environment (or with a jps), and then apply yet another update manifest targetting the docker nodes where I select the node which I want to apply my installation to

Comment: Aaaaaaaaargh even in the case where I preinstall my docker node with some image, if I then apply an update manifest with `targetNodes: docker`, and select the node where I want to install my stuff, then the actions are applied to all nodes satisfying the condition `nodeType: docker`. It's a nightmare.

Comment: > Therefore, I need to update that environment with the addition of new nodes and with some installation steps on those new nodes

You can use the following placeholder  ${event.response.node.id}, so the code will look like (please note comments here do not allow code formatting) 

onAfterAddNode[runner]:
  - cmd[${event.response.node.id}]: echo OK